# Semi-simple controlling operator

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I've just come across this paper by Coleman and Edixhoven called "*On the semi-simplicity of the $U_p$ operator on modular forms*", where (as the title says) they show that the $U_p$ operator is semi-simple on the spaces of cusp forms (Theorem 4.2) under some conditions on the level and $p$.

I was wondering if there is a similar result for Hilbert modular forms or even for quaternionic modular forms?

By similar I mean a result saying that the $U_p$ operator acting in the spaces of cuspidal HMFs or on Quaternionic modular forms is semi-simple given some conditions on the weight, level and $p$.

Thank you